# Iterate through XML to find absolute path

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I'm looking for a way to walk through an XML file and combine the element tags/text into strings. The XML file is a configuration export. I've tried using the iter() method, but it doesn't quite act the way I need it to. Here is the original XML. The examples are truncated for readability.

```
<Configuration product="Cisco Codec" version="ce9.8.0.be9359915d0" apiVersion="4">
  <Audio>
    <DefaultVolume valueSpaceRef="/Valuespace/INT_0_100">70</DefaultVolume>
    <Input>
      <HDMI item="3" maxOccurrence="1">
        <Level valueSpaceRef="/Valuespace/INT_-24_0">-12</Level>
        <Mode valueSpaceRef="/Valuespace/TTPAR_OnOff">On</Mode>
        <VideoAssociation>
          <MuteOnInactiveVideo valueSpaceRef="/Valuespace/TTPAR_OnOff">On</MuteOnInactiveVideo>
        </VideoAssociation>
      </HDMI>
      ....
```

These values would eventually be converted into strings

```
Audio DefaultVolume: 70
Audio Input HDMI 3 Level: -12
Audio Input HDMI 3 Mode: On
Audio Input HDMI 3 VideoAssociation MuteOnInactiveVideo: On
...
```

The XML has a multiple categories of settings. eg `Video Input 2 RGB: On` so I can't hard code the search strings. At the end of the day I'm looking to walk through every element and print out the parent element tags as well as the final element text. There is a consistent pattern of parent elements that don't contain values, then the last element contains the settings value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using lxml and xpath:

```
audio = """[your xml above, fixed"""] #the xml in your example was invalid because closing tags were missing

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(audio.encode('utf-8'))
items = doc.xpath('//Audio//*')
for item in items:
    ancs = []
    if len(item.text.strip())>0:        
        for anc in item.iterancestors():            
            ancs.append(anc.tag)
            if anc.tag == "HDMI":
                ancs.append(anc.xpath('./@item')[0])
        ancs = ancs [:-1]
        ancs.reverse()        
        print(' '.join(ancs),item.tag,':',item.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Audio DefaultVolume : 70
Audio Input 3 HDMI Level : -12
Audio Input 3 HDMI Mode : On
Audio Input 3 HDMI VideoAssociation MuteOnInactiveVideo : On
```

Comment: This approach seems more feasible in achieving what i'm looking to do. I probably should have explained that the XML file will have tons of other properties, not just HDMI. I updated the original question to appropriately reflect the task. At the end of the day, I just need to iterate through every element available, then print it's full path.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use *lxml* here.

Define the following function:

```
def getParentNames(nd):
    res = []
    while True:
        itm = nd.attrib.get('item')
        if itm is not None:
            res.append(itm)
        res.append(nd.tag)    # Current tag name
        nd = nd.getparent()   # Go 1 level up
        if nd is nd.getroottree().getroot():  # Stop before the root node
            res.reverse()
            return ' '.join(res)
```

It returns names of all parent nodes, as a space separated list, but if
some node has *item* attribute, the value of this attribute is added
to this list.

I noticed that you tread *item* attribute in just this "special way",
so this is why I chose just the above solution.

But if you have other "exceptions" concerning special treatment of some
attributes, change the above function accordingly.

Then print the above "paths" and text values of all **leaf** nodes:

```
for nd in root.iter():
    if len(nd.getchildren()) == 0:  # Leaf nodes only
        print(f'{getParentNames(nd)}: {nd.text}')
```

The result is:

```
Audio DefaultVolume: 70
Audio Input HDMI 3 Level: -12
Audio Input HDMI 3 Mode: On
Audio Input HDMI 3 VideoAssociation MuteOnInactiveVideo: On
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Jack's answer, I went ahead and implemented completely what I believe you are looking for. Sadly, it turns out that converting the configuration.xml file to text still misses some entries that the backup includes, such as settings for Bluetooth and experimental features. Still, this script is a great way to create many xCommands out of the configuration.xml file.

This script correctly interprets the item attribute that Cisco uses to differentiate different interfaces. It also adds quotes when the text attribute necessitates them by looking for "STR" in the valueSpaceRef attribute. Hope this helps!

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("configuration.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for node in root.iter():
    if(len(node) == 0):
        isString = False
        if 'STR' in node.attrib['valueSpaceRef']:
            isString = True
        path = tree.getpath(node)
        path = path.split('/')[2:]
        newpath = list()
        for item in path:
            if('[' in item):
                startindex = item.index('[') + 1
                endindex = item.index(']')
                number = item[startindex:endindex]
                item = item[:-3] + " " + number
            newpath.append(item)
        path = newpath
        path = ' '.join(path)
        if(node.text is None):
            node.text = '""'
        elif(isString):
            node.text = '"'+node.text+'"'
        path = path + ': ' + node.text
        print(path)
```